# asp.net mvc. Inserting string data from model into javascript. best-practice

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have to populate javascript code in html layout (hidden fields, method params) with string data from model.

`Html.Encode` is not appropriate for my task because it encodes **'** symbol, bypass **:** (that ruines object attributes declaration) and so on.

I wrote static helper class that is used from View like this:

```
  alert('<%=ViewHelper.MakeJavaScriptSafe(Model.Message)%>');
```

I hope there is asp.net in-built function I don't know about for this task. Does it exist really?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is an Anti-Cross Site Scripting library, [like this one.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973813.aspx)

Comment: I hope asp.net mvc "Html" object will get methods for javascript/html attributes/json safe encoding in the closest future.